# Nemo file manager doesnt remember bookmark on KDE 4.14.2 Debian 8.0.0

Tags: debian, kde, nemo

-- i have installed Nemo file manager from repo ( nemo 2.2.4 ), on My Machine Debian 8.0.0 and im using KDE 4.14.2,
-- my nemo doesnt remember the Bookmark. 
-- i have tried installing nemo from repo,from ubuntu pacthes ( webupd) but no luck,when closing nemo,all the bookmarks lost.

thanks very much for the help.

Azzamsa

Answer (score 0):

[solved]

-- you have to install Nautilus File manager first.
-- so after that you can add your bookmark. and close the nemo without loosing the bookmark you add.

*(after installing nautilus,you can add the bookmark via nautilus or nemo,cause i think both have the same configuration ,cause nemo is the fork from nautilus)